# Mark difference as ok in vimdiff

Tags: vim, vimdiff

I have a couple of large json files that I need to check for errors and was wondering if it is possible to mark a difference as ok and have that apply for the whole diff session thereby eliminating it further down in the file.

example

```
Name: Donald Duck    |   Name: Daisy Duck
```

Here I would like to be able to mark this change as an "ok" diff (i.e. I expect the name and apparent sex change).

Comment: Great question! But sadly I doubt that this is possible.

Comment: Yeah, I think it'd be mentioned in the diff section of the help if it were. All I can think is that you could hack a lot and write a custom diff driver, which reads an auxiliary temporary file containing hunks to ignore, which is populated via a "mark as ok" command within vim... but that's a lot of work.

Comment: Mmmm. It is sort of mentioned. But you have to think creatively. Vim is way too flexible for mre mortals :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the way to do it in vim, would simply to do a custom diff expression

e.g. this should go in your .vimrc

```
set diffexpr=MyDiff()
function! MyDiff()
    let opt = ""
    if &diffopt =~ "icase"
        let opt = opt . "-i "
    endif
    if &diffopt =~ "iwhite"
        let opt = opt . "-Ewb "
    endif
    silent execute "!diff -I 'Duck' " . opt . v:fname_in . " " . v:fname_new .
                \  " > " . v:fname_out
endfunction
```

Of course, you'd want to make it more flexible than that, but this should give you the general method

Comment: Thanks, even though not an easy solution it still is the best I got to work with.

Comment: Thought you could have multiple answers to a question but apparently not =) (still a bit new to stack overflow)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a built-in way to do that. But the way that occurs to me is to do substitute on the files, then rediff.

E.g., if that name change is OK, then just substitute in both files:

```
%s/Name: Donald Duck/Name: placeholder_1/g    ; in file 1
%s/Name: Daisy Duck/Name: placeholder_1/g     ; in file 2
```

You could do this with e.g. sed or perl before starting vim -d as well.

Now those will match. But a change from Donald Duck to Mickey Mouse won't, nor a change from Daffy Duck to Daisy Duck.